# Every time I want to test my android game I have to Build and Run all over again?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Every time I build to test the game it seem to just download the game to my phone and it just stays there. The Play button affects nothing. I can disconnect my phone but the game stays on screen. If I made changes and I want to see again I have to wait through all build and run process again. I didn't have this problem before and I know how it was born?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do have to wait every time i'm afraid.

I am assuming your are using Android. Every time you change the code for your game, the .apk file for the game will be physically different, and so unless you are testing on your PC, you must fully build the game every time you wish to test it on Mobile.

Comment: BUT it wasnt like that before rly , all i had to do is press the play button again and all the changes i did just updated on my phone.

Comment: also do you know how to make the borders of my Camera to be always visible on my Scene , cus i only can see it there when i have selected the Camera in hierarchy.